# Grid with floating number of elements ( depending on their size ) in the row

Tags: react-native

Trying to implement a thingy with no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated.

As much elements as possible should be displayed per row, but only if they fit. Elements might be with different width ( depending on a text ). Everything should be centered.

A picture is worth a thousands words:
[image: How to implement?]

Tried lots of things nothing worked..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use flex? It has to work dynamically

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I mean possible I understand that I can try to take number of characters in text and try to set the flex of View based on how much buttons I intend to put there and how long these buttons will be..

Comment: But I wanted to have something easy and dynamically working like in html :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two useful links in your case https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html and https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexwrap

That code works for me successfully on iOS

```
export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>Hello</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>Some app</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>TV&Internet</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>Remarkable</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>It works</Text></TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 60,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  button: {
    marginBottom: 30,
    width: 'auto',
    marginLeft: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3'
  },
  buttonText: {
    padding: 20,
    color: 'white'
  }
});
```

Comment: It's a CSS property :)

Comment: I am more server-side guy :)